# Fetching multiple rows from Sub Query in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute this query

```
SELECT R1.`report_date`,(SELECT R2.`report_id` FROM `reports` AS R2 WHERE R2.`report_date` = R1.`report_date`) AS DATA FROM `reports` AS R1 GROUP BY R1.`report_date`
```

I am getting this error

```
MySQL said: 

#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

How can I fetch multiple rows from that query ??

Comment: You can fetch single value from subquery if you need multiple value then it should be `concat` or we can say seperated by commas and if you need multiple value then you can use `join` or for single value limit your subquery value to 1

Comment: Thanks @Uchiha. How can I fetch multiple values using **JOIN** ?? Actually I need to fetch multiple values.

Comment: Post the expected output along with the table schema

Comment: I updated my answer can you try that SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I think these SQL will useful to you.

```
SELECT R1.`report_date`,R2.`report_id` AS DATA
FROM `reports` AS R1 ,`reports` AS R2
WHERE R2.`report_date` = R1.`report_date`
GROUP BY R1.`report_date`
```

Can you try  these SQL

```
 SELECT R1.`report_date`,R2.`report_id` AS DATA
    FROM `reports` AS R1 ,`reports` AS R2
    WHERE R2.`report_date` = R1.`report_date`
    GROUP BY R2.`report_id`, R1.`report_date`
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Venkatesh Panabaka. Your query retrieve single value but I would like to fetch multiple values with this query.

Comment: Thanks @Venkatesh Panabaka. Actually I would like to fetch date wise result. Thanks.